# Resizing gtk widgets by user

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, resize

I am working on a project in python using gtk and in it the is a gtk notebook on top of a vte console. I am having trouble getting it to be resizable by the user (i.e. I want the user to be able to drag the border of the 2 up and down and resize both accordingly). Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
vpan = gtk.VPaned()
vpan.show()
vpan.pack1(box1, shrink=False)
vpan.pack2(box2, shrink=False)
```

Comment: Took some fiddling, but I got it working with the vpaned. Thanks :)