# GTK+: Resize widget with mouse

Tags: python, gtk

I'd like users of my sidebar to decide how much size of the screen that sidebar will use. You know, like many programs do: you go to the border of a widget and the pointer becomes an arrow and you can resize that widget.

Is this possible in Gtk? Right now the sidebar is implemented on a Box that has only a button and a ScrolledWindow.

I can copy and paste the code if necessary, but I don't think it'd help much, the question is general enough.

Comment: For sidebars you probably want GtkPaned. How are you doing it now?

Comment: I'm using a simple box. I'll look into GtkPanned, thanks.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4560171/2758435

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Gtk.Paned` to resize your sidebar. Here is an example program that uses it:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class App(Gtk.Window):
    """The window."""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        # The paned window
        self.paned = Gtk.Paned()
        self.add(self.paned)

        # Widets to put in the paned window
        self.label = Gtk.Label(label="Sidebar")
        self.paned.add1(self.label)

        self.button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Something else")
        self.paned.add2(self.button)

        self.show_all()

App()
Gtk.main()
```

Note that you can only add 2 widgets to a `Gtk.Paned` (hence `add1()` and `add2()`). Also, the left pane is automatically downsized to the width of its child on startup.

---

If you want a little more control over how the widgets resize, you can use `pack1()` and `pack2()` instead of `add1()` and `add2()`. The `pack()` functions have two optional arguments: `resize` and `shrink`.

`resize` controls whether the pane resizes to retain it's proportions when its parent widget is expanded, and is `False` by default. So if you set `self.paned.pack1(self.label, resize=True)`, and expand the window, the left pane will expand in order to retain the same width/height ratio. Setting `resize` to `False` will keep the pane at minimum width (the width of its child), even when the `Paned` is resized.

The `shrink` argument controls whether the user can resize the pane to be smaller than its child's size, and is `True` by default. When set to `True`, the user can downsize the pane until it is so narrow it can't be seen, even if the pane's child is bigger than that. When `shrink` is set to `False`, the user can only downsize the pane to its child's size, and no smaller.